# Parsing old tweets and putting their attributes into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, tweepy

I am trying to pull a selection of old tweets and then put various attributes into a Pandas dataframe.  My code is below.  However, when I run the final line, I get a dataframe that only contains attribute data for one tweet rather than for all of them in my selection.

Can someone tell me where my error is?  How do I get each tweet into the dataframe as a separate row?

```
import got3
#Need this to get older tweets

tweetCriteria = got3.manager.TweetCriteria() 
tweetCriteria.setQuerySearch("Kentucky Derby")
tweetCriteria.setSince("2016-05-07") 
tweetCriteria.setUntil("2016-05-08") 
tweetCriteria.setMaxTweets(1000)
#Here I set the parameters for the old tweets I am seeking 

TweetCriteria = got3.manager.TweetCriteria()
KYDerby_tweets = got3.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
#Named my list of tweets

for x in KYDerby_tweets:
    Text = x.text
    Retweets = x.retweets
    Favorites = x.favorites
    Date = x.date
    Id = x.id
    #created variables for each of the attributes I want in the dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame(DataSet)
df
#result here is a 1x6 dataframe containing just one tweet, rather than the 1000x6 dataframe I want, which would contain all of the tweets from my selection...
```

Comment: What is the DataSet object that are using? It isn't defined anywhere in your code. Also, in your for loop you seem to be reassigning variables in every loop, so they get overwritten each time.

Comment: Whoops!  I left that out.  Here is the object: DataSet = [[Id, Date, Text, Favorites, Retweets]]....How do I alter my for loop code to prevent it from re-assigning the variables/overwriting?  That is the core problem, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the clarification from your comment, this should work:

```
# make a list of lists that contain the data
# pandas considers a list of lists to be a list of rows
data_set = [[x.id, x.date, x.text, x.retweets, x.favorites, x.date, x.id] 
            for x in KYDerby_tweets]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_set, columns=["Id", "Date", "Text", "Favorites", "Retweets"])
```